# Word-Wrap Vertical Sliding Text Animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, word-wrap, squarespace

My vertical sliding text animation keeps getting cut off under mobile width. I've been trying to use media queries to target the code but I couldn't get the text and animation to wrap together. How do I adjust my code in order to have the entire animation and text wrap to a reduced width? Thanks!

Here's the HTML & CSS code I'm currently using.

```css
/*Sentence*/

.sentence {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: left;
}


/*Wrapper*/

.wrapper {
  background-color: ;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/*Vertical Sliding*/

.slidingVertical {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 14px;
}

.slidingVertical span {
  animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #00abe9;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.slidingVertical span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.slidingVertical span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}


/*topToBottom Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes topToBottom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes topToBottom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 14px;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #00abe9;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="sentence">A Global Leader in 
    <div class="slidingVertical">
      <span>3PL</span>
      <span>Trading</span>
      <span>Manufacturing</span>
      <span>Warehousing</span>
      <span>Distribution</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```css
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
  color: #222;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.sentence > span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
/*Wrapper*/
.wrapper{
    background-color: ;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Vertical Sliding*/
.slidingVertical{
  display: inline-block;
  width:7em;
  height:1.2em;
  vertical-align: top;
    
}
.slidingVertical span{
     animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: topToBottom 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
     opacity: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.slidingVertical span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*topToBottom Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes topToBottom{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-50px); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(50px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/*Vertical Flip*/
.verticalFlip{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 14px;
}
.verticalFlip span{
    animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="sentence">
    <span>A Global Leader in </span>
    <div class="slidingVertical">
      <span> 3PL</span>
      <span> Trading</span>
      <span> Manufacturing</span>
      <span> Warehousing</span>
      <span> Distribution</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
```

The reason it didn't wrap to the width of the screen was because `.slidingVertical span` used `absolute` positioning, so the container `.slidingVertical` had 0 width.

In the above example, `.slidingVertical` has been changed to be an `inline-block` as wide as the widest span inside it (set manually). This allows the sentence to wrap correctly.